# JAVA ArrayList sort and remove pairs

Tags: java, sorting, object, arraylist

I am trying to write a small card game and have become stuck

I created a class Deck and in it an arraylist of objects, each object represents 1 card in a playing deck comprised of a String suit, String name and an int value from 2-14.
I have created another class for Game with 2 additional arraylists, player1 and player2 and then "dealt" the cards from the arraylist deck to each player.
Before I can continue playing the game I need to remove all pairs from both player1 and player2 arraylist.

I have been trying to sort the arraylist by my getValue() method and then iterate through the arraylist using player1.getValue(i).equals(player1.getValue(i+1) and then remove(i) twice

```
    private void removePlayer1Pairs(ArrayList<Card> player1) {
    Collections.sort(player1);

    int i = 0;
    while(i < player1.size() - 1){
        if(player1.getFaceValue(i).equals(player1.getFaceValue(i+1))){

            player1.remove(i);
            player1.remove(i);

            i = Math.max(0, (i - 1));
        }
        else{
            i++;
          }
    }
}//end removePlayer1Pairs
```

I am getting errors that the method sort is not applicable to Arraylist on line 2 as well as getValue() method is undefined on line 5. Any suggestions making this work? I am just learning arraylists

Comment: For `Collections.sort` to work, `Card` needs to `implement Comparable<Card>`. Can you please show your `Card` class?

Comment: You call `getFaceValue`, not `getValue` as you state in your description. Is that intentional?

Comment: Sort an object Card with Comparator.

Comment: I also have a Deck class

Comment: yes, sorry it is getFaceValue not getValue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although Camparable works for you,there is another option you can use Comparator. For your problem following code works just fine.

```
Collections.sort(player1, new Comparator<Card>() {

        @Override
        public int compare(Card c1, Card c2) {
            Integer a = c1.getFaceValue();
            Integer b = c2.getFaceValue();
            return a.compareTo(b); // for descending order use b.compareTo(a)
        }
    });
```

If you want to sort by other fields like faceValue and suit at the same time, you must have used Comparator.

Answer (score 0):

You can't call sort on an ArrayList of a type you created, how is the sorting algorithm supposed to know what makes one card bigger/smaller than another? Make your Card class implement Comparable, so that sorting can work:

```
public class Card implements Comparable<Card> {
    @Override
    public int compareTo(Card card) {
        //compare card sizes here, i.e Card.value or whatever
    }
```

Now you can sort your cards:

```
Collections.sort(player1);
```

As for removing duplicates, maybe add the ArrayList to a set, which can only contain uniques, and then put it back into an ArrayList?